# Проблема с меню

Tags: html, css

Вот сайтик: http://unioil.org/
Там менюшка сверху. Есть проблемка, что в Google Chrome я растянул ее полностью, а вот в FF и IE обнаружилось, что справа все равно не дотянуто. Код сюда уже не кидаю, на сайте посмотреть можно.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [CSS хаки](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=CSS+%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8&lr=213), я конечно же не решение готовое предлагаю, но как вариант подтянуть знания в области верстки.

```
<!--общий стиль CSS-->
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--Новый набор стилей для IE--> 
<!--[if IE]><link href="styleIE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: никак не выходит

Comment: Что именно не выходит? Делается по такому принципу, верстаете под один браузер, проверяете как отображается в других, если в другом криво, создаете файл *.css например в IE все криво знач файл styleIE.css, после этого подключаете в башке сайта новый стиль, след образом:
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><!--общий стиль CSS-->
<!--[if IE]><link href="styleIE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><![endif]--> <!--Новый набор стилей для IE-->  

Ну и дальше подкручиваете стили под IE в новом файле. Вариантов с хаками море, это и есть решение проблемы кроссбраузерности.

Comment: с IE то разобрался, а как с FF быть?

Answer (score 1):

тут не столько проблема в коде, сколько в организации менюшки, у тебя размер пунктов зависит от размера текста внутри него, а лиса и ослик иначе обрабатывают текст, поэтому у тебя меню не дотягивается, выхода тут 2: 1 - как предлогалось юзать хаки; 2 - прописать для каждого пункта конкретную ширину, и вместо падингов по бокам использовать text-align

Answer (score 0):

А если попробывать для IE

```
li{
 width: 16%; //(100/6)
}
```

Comment: опять же ХАК!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема состоит в том, что браузеры по разному отображают шрифты, один чуть больше, другой чуть меньше - вот и получается в сумме разница в пару пикселей.

У вас сайт фиксированной ширины, так что можете попробовать задавать тоже фиксированную ширину ссылкам, но не забывайте, если что то придется менять - придется пересчитываю величины.

Answer (score 0):

1 - без джс не сделаеш что бы разные пункты меню по ширине тянулись одинкаво.
Сделай все пункты одинаковой ширины и было б все отлично.

Если не устраивает одинаковой ширины юзай джс https://github.com/lukaszklis/AutoScalingMenu